# split() is sometimes not accepted in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a DataFrame, where each cell contains a string text.
In those texts there are some patterns according to which i want to split the string, such that it becomes a list of strings

```
0 'bla bla*bla bla bla*bla'
```

the output should look like

```
0 ['bla bla','bla bla bla','bla]
```

i do this with the following code:

```
splitter = '='*80
df.Text=df.Text.apply(lambda x: x.split(splitter))
```

the strange thing now is, that for some files it works, but for others it says

> 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

even though in the original df.Text both look exactly the same

i read the files using

```
result_list=[]
for file in file_list:
inputlen = file [len(input_path):]
name = inputlen [:12]
with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as     rfile:

    text = rfile.read()
    text = text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    text = text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
a={'TA Date':name, 'Text':text}
result_list.append(a)
df =pd.DataFrame(result_list)
```

so that there can be only one file in one cell

Comment: That error means that some of your values are already lists, i.e., `['bla bla*bla bla bla*bla']` vs `'bla bla*bla bla bla*bla'`. Also, rather than `apply`, you should be able to vectorize the operation with `df['col'].str.split('*')`

Comment: I don't know how, but the error tells you exactly what the problem is. You're trying to call `.split()` on a `list` object. One thing you could do is check `[i for i in df['text'] if type(i) != str]` to find where your column doesn't contain strings

Comment: i've edited my question so that you can see the reading code which creates the dataframe
also if i do `len(df.Text)` the number of entries matches the number of files

Comment: your right i found it, but do you have any idea how this might happen?

Comment: Your best bet is to find those rows in the dataframe, and check the corresponding entries in the input text file

Comment: found my mistake... it was in the further text cleaning...feelin so stupid right now^^
but thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No reason to feel stupid, now you've learned some new techniques for detecting issues with data types. Happy I could help